# How to avoid Listview to reset location after notifyDataSetChanged?

Tags: android, listview, layout, notifydatasetchanged

I put a Listview in the center of the screen.and I start an animation:

```
hideAnimation= new TranslateAnimation(0, -220, 0, 0);
hideAnimation.setDuration(500);
hideAnimation.setFillBefore(false);
hideAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
hideAnimation.setAnimationListener(this);
```

And in method onAnimationEnd, I clear animation and set layout like this:

```
mlistView.layout(-220, 0, 500, 500);
```

and everything works fine so far.
But after the mlistView.layout(-220, 0, 500, 500), I need to refresh my listview.so I just call

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Then my ListView came back to the screen center...

anyone knows how to deal with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

save your location in parameters `x , y , z`
after calling `notifyDataSetChanged` you can do this

```
yourlistView.setLocation(x,y,z);
```

and to your listview add this function

```
public setLocation(int x, int y, int z){
//Do whatever you want
}
```

Comment: At last i use AbsoluteLayout and AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams to set ths location. and it works. thanks for help